# Condition on variable to make events independent

Tags: probability, random-variables, normal-distribution

[image]

where,
$$n_1,n_2,...,n_M \sim N\left(0,\frac{N_0}{2}\right) $$

how the condition on n_1 makes the events independent ? what is "n_1=n"

Answer (score 0):

Conditioning on $n_1=n$ means that when the condition is applied, $n_1$ is constant and no longer random, so no random variable is correlated with it. You then let $n$ vary over all possible values and integrate against the probability of each of these values occurring.